# Basic Question About Integral With Respect to Invariant Measures

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, invariant-theory

Suppose that $(X,\Sigma)$ is a measurable space, $T$ is a measurable map from $(X,\Sigma)$ to itself, and $\mu$ is a $T$-invariant measure.  Define the dynamical system
$$
f_n\triangleq T\circ f_{n-1} ; \qquad f_0\triangleq g; \qquad (\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$),
$$
where $g:X \rightarrow X$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.

*It seems direct from the definition of invariant measure, but just incase I'm missing something:* is it true that
$$
\int_{x \in X} f_n(x) \mu(dx) = \int_{x \in X} g(x) \mu(dx) ;\qquad (\forall n \in \mathbb{N})
?
$$

Comment: It is true  (assuming existence of the integrals) but your definition should be $f_n=f_{n-1} \circ T$.

Comment: Whoops, thanks.  What do you mean the existence of integrals by the way?  Sorry if this is basic, but this is typically not my area of research.

Comment: The integral exists iff the integral of either the positive part (over $\{x\in X:g(x) >0 \}$) or the negative part is finite.

Comment: @AIM_BLB Not every measurable function has an integral.

Comment: Oh this is obvious, I feel silly now :0